# Conversion from scalar to non scalar in c++

Tags: c++

What is the problem with the code below? It is getting compiled in some compilers; but in some compilers it is throwing an error, saying:

```
conversion from scalar to non scalar
```

Can anyone please help with this issue?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class base
{
        typedef std::set<int> Sectors;

        class subclass
        {
                public:
                class subclass2
                {
                        private :
                        Sectors::const_iterator it;
                        public :
                        subclass2(Sectors::const_iterator& it);
                };
                subclass2 begin();

                private:
                Sectors _sectors;
        };
};

base::subclass::subclass2 base::subclass::begin()
{
         return this->_sectors.begin();
}

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error message(s), and also indicate in the source the lines the error message(s) is about.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the conversion constructor:

```
subclass2(Sectors::const_iterator& it);
```

By taking a mutable *lvalue* reference, it can't be called with a temporary; they can only be bound to `const` or *rvalue* references. This line here does just that:

```
return this->_sectors.begin();
```

The fix is to take the argument by `const` reference or by value. Iterators are generally intended to be light-weight things suitable for passing by value, so I'd do that:

```
subclass2(Sectors::const_iterator it);
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::set::begin` returns an iterator to the first element(in your case `std::set<int>::iterator`), not `base::subclass::subclass2`.

You should change your constructor to the following:

```
subclass2(const Sectors::iterator& it);
```

To allow taking temporary objects.

Comment: And `base::subclass::subclass2` has an implicit converting constructor from an iterator, so the problem is more subtle.

Comment: No. `subclass2` has a constructor, accepted `Sectors::const_iterator&`, but `this->_sectors.begin();` has type `Sectors::iterator`.

Comment: That is the subtlety I was referring to. But that is not the end of the story.

Comment: @juanchopanza, still not the end? What am I missed also?

Comment: It is OK, I was referring to the non-`const` reference, but I think you had got that already :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very ugly. Probably you wanted to do as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    typedef std::set<int> Sectors;

    class subclass
    {
    public:
        class subclass2
        {
        private:
            Sectors::const_iterator it;
        public:
            subclass2(Sectors::const_iterator& it);
        };

        Sectors::const_iterator begin(){
            return _sectors.begin();
        }

    private:
        Sectors _sectors;
    };
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is what the OP asking about.

Comment: Apart from rearranging the white-space according to your aesthetics, what have you changed to fix the problem?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, he just changed the return type.